# filtering dataframe column by beginning of string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to filter the following dataframe rows by the beginning 19 characters **(meets requirements)** of a string.

As of now the dataframe looks like this:

```
        Name    Reason
   0    item1   {"state": "doesn't meet requirements" , "score": "0.6"}
   1    item2   {"state": "meets requirements" , "score": "0.7"}
   2    item3   {"state": "meets requirements" , "score": "0.8"}
   3    item4   {"state": "doesn't requirements" , "score": "0.9"}
   4    item5   {"state": "meets requirements" , "score": "0.7"}
   5    item6   {"state": "doesn't requirements" , "score": "0.7"}
```

the result I am looking is for the dataframe to look like this:

```
    Name    Reason
0   item2   {"state": "meets requirements" , "score": "0.7"}
1   item3   {"state": "meets requirements" , "score": "0.8"}
2   item5   {"state": "meets requirements" , "score": "0.7"}
```

basically filtering so that the only rows left are the ones that begging with "meets requirements" in the "Reason" column

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered putting the score into a separate column?

Comment: I did, but the reason column comes from a json file, so I don't think I can separate them.

Comment: Of course you can. You might not want/need to, but you certainly can.

Comment: In fact one solution immediately leads to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#strip the spaces and compare with the prefix and then filter the rows 
df[df.Reason.str.replace(' ','').str.startswith('{"state":"meetsrequirements"')]
Out[236]: 
     Name                                            Reason
1   item2  {"state": "meets requirements" , "score": "0.7"}
2   item3  {"state": "meets requirements" , "score": "0.8"}
4   item5  {"state": "meets requirements" , "score": "0.7"}
```

Comment: You might prefer using regex to the replacement, but this works.